# Как расширить строку с помощью realloc?

Tags: c, realloc

Как можно расширить динамический символьный массив (строку) с помощью `realloc()`?

Comment: Не пользоваться им, Выделить новую память, ручками туда все перенести, освободить старую.

Answer (score 9):

Часто можно увидеть примерно такой код:

```
char *string = malloc(...);
/* ... */
string = realloc(...);
```

Этот код содержит распространенную ошибку: если выполнение `realloc` завершилось неудачно, то в `string` будет записан `NULL` и мы потеряем доступ к указателю, который был изначально получен вызовом `malloc`. Следовательно, получим утечку памяти.

Правильным идеоматичным решением будет записывать результат выполнения `realloc` во временную переменную, проверять успешеность вызова `realloc`, и только затем (если вызов был успешен) перезаписывать исходную переменную:

```
char *string = malloc(...);

if (string == NULL) {
    /* ... */
}  

/* ... */

char *temp = realloc(string, ...);

if (temp != NULL) {
    string = temp;
}
```

*Важно отметить, что при успешном выполнении `realloc` деаллоцирует старый объект, поэтому сразу после выполнения `realloc` указатель `string` в становится невалидным и не может быть использован в дальнейшем.*

---

Полный пример:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *s = malloc(6);

    if (s == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can not malloc().\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    strcpy(s, "hello");
    puts(s);

    char *temp = realloc(s, 14);

    if (temp == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can not realloc().\n");
        free(s);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    s = temp;

    strcpy(s, "hello, world!");
    puts(s);

    free(s);
}
```

Comment: "Важно отметить, что realloc деаллоцирует старый объект," - не, не обязательно. И память в примере нужно освобождать.

Comment: @KoVadim, «The realloc function **deallocates** the old object pointed to by ptr and returns a pointer to a new object that has the size specified by size».

Comment: @KoVadim, хотя, забыл написать, что не деаллоцируется, если вызов был неуспешен. Сейчас поправлю.

Comment: @KoVadim, спасибо за замечания.

Comment: опять же, читайте документацию внимательно. malloc может выделить немного больше памяти, чем нужно (никто не будет выделять 3 или 5 байт - округлят к 16 в худшем случае. А то и больше). и в этом случае realloc ничего не будет удалять-перевыделять - поправит размер выделенной области и готово.

Comment: @KoVadim, выделенный кусок не всегда можно увеличить, и приходится выделять новый уже в другом месте. Тем более, я говорю о стандарте языка, а не о конкретных реализациях. Пользоваться старым указателем в общем случае нельзя в независимости от реализации. Я не уверен на счет ситуации, когда старый указатель может иметь то же значение, что и новый. По-моему, даже два указателя с одним и тем же значением, но полученные разными вызовами аллоцирующих функция считают неравными. Сейчас поищу информацию об этом.

Comment: @KoVadim, да, «два указателя равны тогда и только тогда, когда оба являются нулевыми, либо указывают на **один и тот же объект** (в том числе указатель на объект и первый подобъект в составе объекта) или функцию, либо указывают на позицию за последним элементом массива, либо один указатель ссылается на позицию за последним элементом массива, а другой — на начало другого массива, следующего сразу за первым в том же адресном пространстве».

Comment: @eanmos, в реальном мире 2 указателя с одинаковым значением адресуют одно и то же, а `realloc` часто возвращает тот же адрес (если есть возможность, то память не копируется). Кстати, опять же в реальном мире, если realloc возвращает 0, то для большинства программ единственным разумным решением будет аварийное завершение с "out of memory"

Comment: @avp, про деаллокацию я написал к тому, что если этого не учитывать, то 1) будет UB при попытке использования деаллоцированного указателя; 2) даже если UB пройдет безболезненно, в дальнейшем могут быть проблемы из-за того, что два одинаковых по значению указателя считаются неравными (внутри какого-нибудь условия, например). Вам может быть интересна [эта](https://habr.com/ru/company/pvs-studio/blog/418023/) статья.

Comment: @eanmos, ага я прочитал и даже проверил примеры на `gcc version 7.4.0 (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1)`. Все изменилось (бред из сравнения указателей исчез). Очевидно кому-то удалось убедить реализаторов GCC, что надо лучше шевелить своими мозгами и адекватно реагировать на запросы практиков

Comment: @avp, а вы не забыли `-O1`? С `-O1` GCC 9.2.0 все еще выдает `0x7ffe6868d960 0x7ffe6868d960 0`.

Comment: @eanmos, в самом деле, с любой оптимизацией выдает 0. Что же, рано я о них начал хорошо думать (надо будет на работе на всякий случай проверить, что генерится в подобном случае)

Comment: @avp, тут скорее стандарт менять надо. Хотя, там ведь тоже не дураки сидят, сейчас спрошу на enSO по этому поводу.

Comment: @eanmos, конечно, ноги растут именно оттуда (насчет заседающих не знаю, вспоминается *"согласие есть продукт непротивления сторон"*)

Comment: @eanmos ох ох. Не нужно мне это все объяснять, я знаю это все. Но Ваши рассуждения - из соседней оперы.

Comment: @KoVadim, я рад, что вы это все знаете, но я так и не понял, почему мои рассуждения «из соседней оперы».

Comment: @eanmos Выб хоть указатели бы приводили от void* к Вашим

Comment: @Maggot, кастить результат `*alloc` в C [не стоит](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/8086115).

Comment: @eanmos добро) спасибо)

Comment: @eanmos, хотите посмеяться? (хоть говорят и грешно над больными людьми...) `int a, b;
  int *p = &a;
  int *q = &b - 1;

  if (p != q)
    printf("%ld\n", p - q);` (это по мотивам  примера из вашей ссылки) **печатает 0**

Comment: @avp, здесь же, вроде, UB, потому что «When two pointers are subtracted, **both shall point to elements of the same array object**, or one past the last element of the array object; the result is the difference of the subscripts of the two array elements». Хотя, конечно, выглядит это все о-очень странно.

Comment: @eanmos, большинство их UB выглядят странно (мягко говоря). Вот обращение по не инициализированному указателю или т.п. вещи (в т.ч. неатомарный доступ к памяти из разных threads) это очевидное UB (**undefined** behavior), зависит только от текущего состояния вычислительной системы, которое в данный момент принципиально не предсказуемо. А все остальное это надуманные вещи (да, в разных системах программирования и на разном железе результаты могут быть разными, но они предсказуемы и (imho) должны называться чем-то вроде system defined)

Comment: @avp, ну по-сути неопределены-то (undefined) они только стандартом, а при исполнение всегда происходит что-то определенное (пусть и не всегда прогнозируемое). Кстати, что интересно, чтение неинициализрованной переменной — это не всегда UB. Если мы читаем из неинициализированной переменной типа `unsigned char`, которая заведома не может хранится в регистре (т. е. можно просто применить к ней оператор взятия адреса `&`), то получим unspecified value. Не знаю, чем вызвано такое странное решение, но имеем то, что имеем.

Comment: А разве не надо освободить ещё temp?

Comment: @DrSAN4ez, нет, мы же сохраняем значение `temp` в `s`. А после того как `s` перестает быть нужным, его действительно следует освободить.