# Изменения размерности динамического массива через функцию(принцип работы realloc())

Tags: c, массивы, указатели, динамические-массивы, realloc

По условию, пользователь имеет возможность изменить размер динамического массива. Код для выполнения этой операции должен реализовываться через функцию. Соответственно, при передаче массива в функцию (указателя), мы изменяем его размерность перераспределяя память с помощью функции `realloc()`.

Возвращает ли `realloc` указатель, который указывает на отличную ячейку памяти, нежели тот указатель который мы передавали в функцию? То есть следует ли нам возвращать из функции изменения размерности массива новый указатель и присваивать его нашему указателю в теле главной функции, чтобы в дальнейшем обрабатывать массив в других функциях?

Либо же можно ничего не возвращать, потому что ячейка памяти, на которую указывает указатель не изменяется при использовании `realloc()`?
На практике оба варианта дают корректные результаты, но в документации и прочих источниках на просторах  интернета указано, что `realloc()` может перезаписать данные в новый блок памяти с новым адресом.

Как корректнее поступать?

Comment: Правильно считать, что realloc вернет **новый адрес** (видимо ваши попытки получить результаты на практике были некорректны)

Comment: https://elixir.bootlin.com/glibc/latest/source/hurd/hurdmalloc.c#L318 и https://elixir.bootlin.com/glibc/latest/source/malloc/memusage.c#L379 развлекайтесь

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ответ @AlexGlebe не совсем верен.

---

Откроем стандарт C99 (жирное выделение — моё):

> #### 7.20.3.4 The realloc function
>
> **Synopsis**
>
> ```c
> #include <stdlib.h>
> void *realloc(void *ptr, size_t size);
> ```
>
> **Description**
>
> The `realloc` function **deallocates the old object pointed to by `ptr`** and returns a pointer to a new object that has the size specified by size. The contents of the new object shall be the same as that of the old object prior to deallocation, up to the lesser of the new and old sizes. Any bytes in the new object beyond the size of the old object have indeterminate values.
>
> If `ptr` is a null pointer, the `realloc` function behaves like the `malloc` function for the specified size. Otherwise, if `ptr` does not match a pointer earlier returned by the `calloc`, `malloc`, or `realloc` function, or if the space has been deallocated by a call to the free or realloc function, the behavior is undefined. If memory for the new object cannot be allocated, the old object is not deallocated and its value is unchanged.
>
> **Returns**
>
> The `realloc` function returns a pointer to the new object (which may have the same value as a pointer to the old object), or a null pointer if the new object could not be allocated.

Таким образом со стороны API стандартной библиотеки C есть всего две ситуации:

1. Вызов `realloc` был успешен (вызов вернул не `NULL`). В таком случае **старый указатель является невалидным** и любой доступ к нему вызывает неопределенное поведение. **Даже если старый указатель указывает на тот же участок памяти, что и новый**.
2. Вызов `realloc` вернул `NULL`. В таком случае старый указатель остается валидным, как будто никакого вызова `realloc` и не происходило.

---

Если резюмировать, ты вы никогда не должны полагаться на то, что указатель, возвращенный `realloc` будет равен (в смысле оператора `==`) или иметь то же самое значение (указывать на тот же самый объект в памяти), что и старый указатель.

И да, два указателя могут иметь одинаковое значение, но не быть равными:

```c
int *p, *q;

/* ...  */

if (p != q)
    printf("%p != %p", (void *) p, (void *) q); /* 0x100 != 0x100 (может быть и такое) */
```

---

О правильном и идеоматичном использовании функции `realloc` я уже писал [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1070791/185348).

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120213/discussion-on-answer-by-eanmos-----).

Answer (score 3):

Возникает три ситуации :

Возвращается тот-же адрес например, если вы уменьшали размер или память дальше свободна и хватает места.

Возвращается новый адрес, если для дальнейшего роста размера выделенного участка памяти не хватает места. И на новый участок памяти все данные будут скопированы. Предыдущий указатель будет уже неликвидный.

Возвращается **NULL** если для выделения памяти не хватает ни физической памяти ни свопа (на винчестерах). Или программа превысила лимит использования памяти. Или разные системные требования не выполнены (*например размер памяти должен быть только кратным **0x1000** байт*).

Чтобы все ситуации правильно обработать нужен минимально такой код :

```
int * newpointer = realloc ( pointer , newsize ) ;
if ( newpointer != NULL ) {
  pointer = newpointer ;
  arraysize = newsize ; }
else {
  // память не выделена, старая остаётся на прежнем месте
  // программа должна сама подумать как выходить из этой ситуации
  }
```

Comment: поправлю: `NULL` возвращается при любой ошибке выделение памяти, но «нехватака» физ. памяти на взрослых системах IRL, по факту таковой не является. Скорее будет отказ со стороны ОС по причинам ограничения для данного процесса, исчерпание виртуального адресного пространства или чрезмерной фрагментации его или кучи... реальное исчерпание памяти обычно наступает совершенно не в тот момент, когда процесс её запрашивает, а когда он начинает её использовать и в таком случае ОС обычно просто кого-нибудь убивает...